# WebMethods integration server on linux

Tags: linux, esb, webmethods

Has anyone ever implemented the SoftwareAG WebMethods Enterprise Integration Suite on the Linux platform ? If so, what has been your experience with it ?

Answer (score 0):

The SoftwareAG WebMethods Integration Server runs within a JVM, no matter where it is installed. It doesn't matter if the JVM runs on windows or linux.

What you have to ask yourself is how familiar are you with linux as an operating system vs windows as an operating system.

Pick the one that you're most familiar with.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think webmethods can be installed in any OS where JVM is installed. For example I initially tried to install webmethods on Ubuntu Assuming the same but later on I came to know that SoftwareAG webmethods can only be installed on windows/Linux.

What ever it is , either Linux or Windows, Webmethods runs on JVM. Good or Bad depends on how familiar you are on the OS.

Comment: Ubuntu is a Linux.